# Unit testing an existing app with iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: unit-testing, ios6, ios7

I am working on a app for unit testing it. It is compatible with iOS 6 as well as with iOS 7. I have added test cases in it using iOS 7 but I also want it to get tested with iOS 6.

As iOS 7 uses XCTest framework, if I am trying to add senTestingKit then it gives me an error and is not running the tests. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you post what the error is? And are you sure you are linking against the SenTestingKit instead of XCTTest framework?

Comment: This question needed an [mcve] and was/is not answerable in this state. I believe it should be closed for now.